# Scoped css class with elements

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I use vue with vuetify. I have to use sass to override the style of vuetify components.
With the following code I want to update the style of my text field.

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
.center {
    input {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
</style>
```

Without the scope attribute it works. But how do I make it work and only apply the current component?

```
<v-text-field v-model="myText" class="center" @input="onTextInput" />
```

Thanks

Comment: please create a working snippet with a MVCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Vue2 you need to add `::v-deep` before the class.

Ex:

```
::v-deep .target-class {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

For Vue3

```
:deep(.target-class) {
  background-color: #000;
}
```